# Run Chromium from shell script (Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am writing a script to check and restart wifi on a raspberry pi. It should also kill and relaunch chromium. I have set a job to run every minute from crontab, that command is:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/checkwifi.sh
```

Inside of checkwifi.sh:

```
ping -c4 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0]
then
    sudo /sbin/ifdown 'wlan0'
    sleep 5
    sudo /sbin/ifup --force 'wlan0'
    sudo pkill chromium
    sleep 10
    /usr/bin/chromium --kiosk "http://some-website-here"
fi
```

Everything up to launching chromium works, including killing any running instance of chromium. The last line errors out silently, or at least I haven't found any error logging.

Additionally, if I run...

```
/usr/local/bin/checkwifi.sh
```

...from terminal, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from top of my head, maybe problem is the display environment value?

Try 'export DISPLAY=:0.1' or whatever display number your Xorg has.

Comment: This is a type of response that normally should be posted as a comment (but since you don’t have yet enough reputation points to post comments, I’m not sure what alternative you have as a far as trying to help).

Comment: Yes, you can only post comments for main post if you have 50+ rep.
Since op did not provided enough info to debug for full answer... that's the only help that we could provide. :/

Comment: It's OK because that ended up being the correct solution anyways!